# Mapping to two different method in Spring controller based on header content

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have to implement the same endpoint that return different data type. I can't use versioning in the URL so just wondering how I can use header content to map request to based on header value.

For example I will be sending `val1` or `val2` in header say `decider`. And I want to have controller methods like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "\someUrl")
public firstReturnType someMethod() {

} 

@RequestMapping(value = "\someUrl")
public secondReturnType someOtherMethod() {

}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: `@RequestMapping` has [`headers`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#headers--) property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the HTTP Headers list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

you can see that you don't have in HTTP headers that you can use to your needs or any other custom needs.

I would recommend differentiating between the 2 methods by adding HTTP verb, GET, POST, DELETE, PUT.

Or just change your URL to:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/someUrl/{id}")
```

Or just use one method and use if statement to decide which answer to return:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/someUrl")
public firstReturnType someMethod(@RequestParam("param") int param ) {
    if(param == 1){
        ...
    }
    else if(param == 2){
        ...
    }
}
```